# PHP how to retrieve data from an object return

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a return value and I `var_dump()` to get the data.

`var_dump($values)`

this is the result:

```
object(WP_Error)#171 (2) { ["errors":"WP_Error":private]=> array(1) { ["upload_error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "0B1n5jy1RsUExUWNCN01GeXBvWmM" } } ["error_data":"WP_Error":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

I am new with PHP Object retrieving I tried `foreach` but noting happens.

what I am trying to do is to get this value:

`["upload_error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "0B1n5jy1RsUExUWNCN01GeXBvWmM" }`

the `0B1n5jy1RsUExUWNCN01GeXBvWmM` that set on `upload_error`

Comment: 1. Have you tried something ? 2. Please just learn the basics how to access an array or object property

Comment: Or read the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) on how to catch errors from `WP_Error`

Comment: Ensure plz that this is really result of a `var_dupm($some_oject)`. Because what you have shown; does not seem to be really an object

Answer (score 0):

1. `WP_Error` is a php class, your `values` is a instance. see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error for detail
2. if you want to get error, you can't get it directly because it is private( although you can see it in var_dump), the doc above will tell you how to get it via provided public methods.
3. the following code snippet may give you a better understanding for using `foreach` on a class instance. you can look at manual for more detail. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

   ```
   class WP_Error_Example
   {
       private $errors = array();
       public $pk = 1;
   }

   $e = new WP_Error_Example();
   $e2 = new WP_Error_Example();

   // #1,#2 in var_dump shows how many instance? 
   var_dump($e);
   var_dump($e2);

   // only public value 
   foreach ($e as $k => $v) {
       var_dump($k, $v);
   }
   ```

Note: you need to save this to a single file and run it using commandline. eg:`php demo.php` PS: `var_dump` it not pretty in commandline.